# Finding what gone wrong by checking GDB

Tags: c, gdb

When I open the core file which has been created by my software I see:

```
 0x0000000800d2afc7 in g_slice_set_config () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
 0x0000000800d2b21b in g_slice_set_config () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
 0x0000000800d2b703 in g_slice_free1 () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
 0x00000000004a027d in user_free (user=0x859945bc0) at user/user.c:178
 0x00000000004a016c in user_exit () at user/user.c:349
 0x000000000049e865 in dpi_exit () at dpi.c:465
 0x00000000004156ae in worker_run () at itapworker.cpp:818
 0x00000000004168fc in worker_main (wptr=0x8006a7124) at itapworker.cpp:957
 0x0000000000416ddb in spawn_newworker (wptr=0x8006a7124) at itapworker.cpp:265
 0x0000000000416ee6 in spawn_workers () at itapworker.cpp:162
 0x0000000000414569 in main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffebc0) at itap.cpp:463
```

The code I am familiar with in my project is `user_free`. Inside of `user_free`:

```
 static inline void
 user_free(dpi_user_t *user)
 {
    if (user->policy)
        policy_rem_ref(user->policy);
    user_remove(user);
    g_slice_free(dpi_user_t, user);
 }
```

When I print suspicious pointers:

```
 (gdb) print user
 $5 = (dpi_user_t *) 0x859945bc0
 (gdb) print user->policy
 $6 = (rbpe_policy_t *) 0x80b1acc20
```

Because the core happens in the one free function, only thing comes to my mind is null pointer access. But when I check pointers they are not null at all. 
Do you guys have any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: What caused the core dump? There are several reasons why a process might dump core, not just segfaults, which you kinda-sorta allude to but don't say.

Comment: Freeing already freed memory?

Comment: pointer may point to out of process memory

Comment: @jxh I believe most logical approximation, stdcall print user->policy seem valid so user is valid pointer.